# QtQuick, QThread, and signals integration

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I have very simple application which can be seen at my github: https://github.com/lejmr/qtquicktest

What I realized is when my *cppSlot*  is called and takes too long to finish my GUI gets irresponsible. Therefore, I decided to initiate a new Thread when calling my *cppSlot* function such that I updated my connect section to:

```
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    analyzeSignal.moveToThread(thread);
    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(doAnalyzeSignal(QString,QString,QString,QString)),
&analyzeSignal, SLOT(cppSlot(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
 thread->start();
```

However, if I do that I get this error:

QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

(Parent is `QQuickTextDocumentWithImageResources(0x2ae4de0)`, parent's thread is `QThread(0x20081e0)`, current thread is `QThread(0x2302730)`

I think it is caused by https://github.com/lejmr/qtquicktest/blob/master/main.cpp#L15 where I propagate wrong pointer (onto the original thread, but signal is initiated from different thread).

I tried whole bunch of things, but I haven't managed to succeed.

The goal is to write output of called program into an textfield in GUI instead of putting it to console.

Answer (score 0):

You are just trying to thread something right? just connect the signal to a slot that calls the function using `QtConcurrent::run`

```
QtConcurrent::run(this, &whateverYourClassIsCalled::cppSlot, param1, param2, etc);
```